# IIS URL Rewrite QueryString Parameter to subdomain

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, subdomain

I need to rewrite the URL using a QS parameter as subdomain:

Something like this:
`https://mysite.example/?subdomain=test&user=10042` ===> `https://test.mysite.example/?user=10042`

All examples I've found convert subdomains to QueryString (seems more popular), so did not found helpful solutions: I made something like this but it does not work

```
<rule name="QS to Subdomain">
 <match url=".*" >
 <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="subdomain=([a-z0-9]+)" />  
 </conditions>
 <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}.mysite.example/" /> 
</rule>
```

Can pls help to understand how to achieve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this rule:

```
<rule name="QS to Subdomain">
  <match url=".*" >
    <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
      <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="subdomain=([a-z0-9]+)&(.*)" />  
    </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}.mysite.example/?{C:2}" /> 
</rule>
```

Comment: hmm.. I have to manage a third parameter so I slightly modified, but your examples helped me to better understand urlrewrite. Now it works.. but with `action.type=Redirect ` and not `Rewrite`: why you both wrote `Rewrite`?

Comment: This depends on your choice, because the case you provided uses rewrite, redirect rules are typically used for old paths that you'd like to redirect to new ones. In contrast, a Rewrite rule does not change the original URL; it simply serves the content of the rule destination at the original path.

Comment: Sorry to bother you.. but I do not understand: if it is my choice it should work with both `Rewrite` and `Redirect`, while with `Rewrite` it return a wrong page or even `HTTP Error 404.4 - Not Found`
Therefore there is still something wrong in my code, and there's something I've not understood :-(
Anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: You can use [failed request tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) to view detailed error information, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve what you're looking for using:

```
<rule name="QS to Subdomain" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="subdomain=([^&amp;]+)" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="http://{C:1}.mysite.example/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

1. `stopProcessing = true` to ensure that no other rules is processed after a match is found.
2. Update the regular expression pattern to `subdomain=([^&amp;]+)`.

Comment: Hi!
I (partially) fixed using `Redirect` instead of `Rewrite`
But I had to  set `appendQueryString='false'` elsewhere it enter a loop.
Unfortunately, in this  way, I lose the `userid` parameter: one solution could be to apply this rule only when `url` does not have a subdomain, but I've not find the way to do it :-(